# Assigning the value of a method to a variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In Objective-C, how do I assign the return value of a method to a variable of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you having any problem with:

```
- (NSString *)getString {
  return @"hehe";
}

NSString *myString = [self getString];
```

You need to put the method getString above the assigning or defining the getString in the interface

Answer (score 1):

Say your method prototype looked like this:

```
- (NSString *) name;
```

You'd create a variable to hold the return value like this:

```
NSString *some_name = [obj name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you method returns an array
-(NSMutableArray *)getArray;

then NSMutableArray *arr=[self getArray];

or if a function return an object of a class

```
-(Class *)getObjectOfClass;
```

then you can hold this object like

```
Class *objClass=[self getObject];
```

means by simply assigning the return value to same type of variable.you can access that.